# MonoTouch exited with code 134 after buying a license

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created an iPhone project using MonoTouch Evaluation version. It worked fine on iPhone Simulator. Then, I bought the Professional license, deleted evaluation copy of MonoTouch, downloaded the installer from store.xamarin.store account and installed it using Offline Activation. From then on, I'm unable to build the project. When I create an entirely new project, it doesn't build with the same exact error as in the question title.

Part of the build output:

    `at (wrapper managed-to-native) Sys.get_serial () <0xffffffff>
    at Sys.get_Serial () <0x0000b>
    at MTouch.Main (string[]) <0x00507>
    at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int_object(object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>`

The build ends with error 134. Can anyone help me with that?
I'm using the iOS 5.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth contacting support@xamarin.com for them to help you out with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already did that. It's just there's a huge time difference between my location and xamarin's location and they start working exactly when I'm leaving for home, so I thought SO might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the OS language has to be set to US/English. All thanks go to Xamarin's support. It's kinda crazy that this is the case though...